# No colors when using autospec

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec, autotest, zentest

When I'm using autospec to test a non-Rails Ruby project, I always have trouble getting my tests to show up red or green.

When I run a regular 'spec spec/ --color' command I get normal red/green responses. I've tried putting all sorts of commands in the .autotest file and I can't get that to work.

Also, in my Rails projects, I don't get this problem.

Note:
I do have the ZenTest(4.2.1) and redgreen (1.2.2) gems installed.
I'm currently trying to get it working with this project: http://github.com/coreyhaines/kata-number-to-led

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autospec reads a configuration file at `spec/spec.opts` for options. Make sure rspec can find this file and that it has the `--color` option (or `--colour` for our British friends).